# Universal mapping property and field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

The following is a portion of notes for an introduction to Galois theory (I am not in the course):

There are possible details missing but I can't find a similar discussion using the universal property.

> Let $f(x) \in k[x]$ be irreducible and for $\beta$ a root of $f(x)=0$ in a field extension $K$ of $k$, there is a $k$-algebra map $k(\alpha) \to K$ such that $\phi(\alpha)=\beta$. To prove this note that by the universal property of $k[x]$, there is a unique $k$-algebra homomorphism $k[x] \to \overline{k}$ sending $x$ to $\beta$. The kernel is the ideal generated by the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ which is $f(x)$, and thus this map factors through $k[x]/ f$ which is isomorphic to $k(\alpha)$

**Question 1:** Is $\alpha \in K$ (or $\alpha \in \overline{k}$, not entirely clear) also a root of $f(x)=0$? From my understanding, it is only true that $k(\alpha) \cong k[x]/f$ if $f(\alpha)=0$.

**Question 2:** Assuming $\alpha$ is a root. Using the idea of "factors trough" there exists $\psi: k[x]/f \to \overline{k}$ such that $\psi(\overline{x})=\beta$, where $\overline{x}$ represent the image of $x$ in the projection $k[x] \to k[x] / f$. I want to identify $\overline{x}$ with $\alpha$ through the isomorphism to get $\psi(\alpha)=\beta$. However, this is a bit hand wavy and we still only have that $\psi(\beta) \in \overline{k}$, and we want $\beta \in K$.

Anyway, I apologize for this question being a bit confusing and would appreciate any attempt at an explanation.

Comment: I think the first thing that needs clearing up here is: what definition are you using of $k(\alpha)$? In particular, clearing up where $\alpha$ lives is probably pretty important. As for the second question, it seems to have been a previously established fact that the map sending $\bar x$ to $\alpha$ is a field isomorphism between $k[x]/f$ and $k(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, yes, $\alpha$ ought to be a root. (It is  not necessarily in $K$.)

For the second question, in the same way as for $\beta$, you have an isomorphism $k[x]/f \to k[\alpha] = k(\alpha)$ sending $x$ to  $\alpha$; the inverse of that isomorphism does what you need.

It is not quite clear to me what you mean with:

> and we still only have that $\psi(\beta) \in \overline{k}$, and we want $\beta \in K$.

First, I think you mean $\psi(\alpha)= \beta$. And, $\beta$ was assumed to be in $K$. I see that you are likely worried that the map goes to $\overline{k}$ and not $K$. But the image is just $k[\beta]$ which is in $K$. (It is not quite clear to me why $\overline{k}$ is brought up at that point at all.)